# Postgres optimization to show frontend results

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I have my frontend in angularjs and the backend is written in Node.js.

I'm having issues doing search in my frontend because the result query takes too long... My machine have 2 CPU's (2.67) and 8GB of RAM.

I have a rest request from the frontend to my backend rest api, which will make a request to the database using pg.

Is there a way to decrease the search time optimizing postgres? I'm using a http proxy server and a server in separate instances.

I tried to use pgtune but didn't help.

Frontend:

```
var url = '/api/logs/?device_id='+controllerScope.device;   // get distinct type from bd with logs database for default_dataset

            if (interval.start !== undefined) {
                url += '&start_timestamp='+interval.start;
            }
            if (interval.end !== undefined) {
                url += '&end_timestamp='+interval.end;
            }

            $http.get(url).success(function (data) { 

            }
```

Rest Api....

**Controller**

```
LogsController.prototype.getLogTypes = function (req, res, next) {
    createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getLogTypes', 'inicio');
    var endTimestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var startTimestamp = 0;

    if (req.query.end_timestamp !== undefined) {
        endTimestamp = req.query.end_timestamp;
    }

    if (req.query.start_timestamp !== undefined) {
        startTimestamp = req.query.start_timestamp;
    }

    Database.Logs.getLogTypesByDevice(req.query.device_id, startTimestamp, endTimestamp).then(function (types) {
        if (types.length == 0) {
            res.status(204).end();
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(types);
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getLogTypes', e);
        res.status(500).send(e);
    });

}
```

**Database**

```
LogsDatabase.prototype.getLogTypesByDevice = function (deviceId, startTimestamp, endTimestamp) {
    createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), deviceId, 'getLogTypesByDevice', 'inicio');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pg.connect(dbHistConnectionString, function (err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), deviceId, 'getLogTypesByDevice', err);
                reject(err);
                return
            }
            client.query("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp) AS timestamp, medium, type,agregation_period, labels FROM default_dataset WHERE device_id = $1 AND timestamp >= to_timestamp($2) AND timestamp <= to_timestamp($3)",
                    [deviceId, startTimestamp, endTimestamp], function (err, result) {
                done();
                if (err) {
                    createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), deviceId, 'getLogTypesByDevice', err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result.rows);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: How fast is it if you run the query in `psql`? It could just be that you need to create an index.

Comment: I have a index in device_id and timestamp, I did the explain in the query and it returns Sort  (cost=820645.97..821278.07 rows=252841 width=125)

Comment: Please post the output of the explain plan.

Comment: I've updated my question and include a image